# How to plot splines in a coxph model that includes a frailty term?

Tags: r, survival, cox-model, splines, frailty

I have a Cox PH model including a smoothing spline and a frailty term as follows:

```
fit<-coxph(Surv(start,end,exit) ~ x + pspline(z) + frailty(a))
```

When I run a model without a frailty term, I use the following in order to plot the splines:

```
termplot(fit, term = 2, se = TRUE, ylab = "Log Hazard", rug=TRUE, xlab = "z_name")
```

However, when the frailty term is included, it gives this error:

```
Error in pred[, first] : subscript out of bounds
```

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks.